# I got this error string was not recognized as a valid datetime when I validate WPF DatePicker control

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF application, with a WPF Toolkit DatePicker control bound to a DateTime variable as following:

```
<myToolkit:DatePicker Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="clndrHiredate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontWeight="Light" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectedDate="{Binding bindingDate,StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}', Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" x:Name="btnRead" Height="29" Content="Read" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FF47594E" Margin="64,13,31,196" Width="65" />
```

And my code :

```
private DateTime bindingDate = DateTime.Now;

private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clndrHiredate.SelectedDate.ToString()))
      {
          errorText += MessageBox.show("Wrong");
          state = true;
          lblHireDate.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }
      else
      {
          // complete 
      }
}
```

but when I run this , I got error message "string was not recognized as a valid datetime."

If there is any error, How do I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `SelectedDate.ToString()` to `DateTime.TryParse(clndHireDate.Text)` to see if it is a valid datetime.